# Role of 'for them' in this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning

What is the role of 'for them' in the following sentence? Could it be omitted without any change in meaning?

> The only way for unions to maintain their clout would be **for them** to organise internationally.

(emphasis by me)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it could be missed out. That's because the unions are the effective subject of *maintain their clout*, and thus they are also the implied subject of *to organise internationally*. They are the only possible subject in that sentence.

However, consider the sentence:

> The only way we'll see unions maintain their clout would be for them to organise internationally.

In that case, if it weren't for ***for them***, it could be that the sentence is suggesting that *we* organise internationally, rather than the unions. The relative pronouns *them* indicates that it's the unions, and as they are the only third-person in the sentence they are the only possible antecedent of *them*.